# Select Distinct rows based on ID relative to reference date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a report that takes a given reference date and brings back the relevant closest date row. This should bring back one row per ID (person). For example, the table in SQL looks like this:

| ID | Name | Value | Effective From |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 100 | 01/01/2023 |
| 1 | Tom | 50 | 01/01/2022 |
| 1 | Tom | 25 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2 | Sam | 100 | 01/01/2023 |
| 2 | Sam | 50 | 01/01/2022 |
| 2 | Sam | 25 | 01/01/2021 |
| 3 | Matt | 100 | 01/01/2023 |
| 3 | Matt | 50 | 01/01/2022 |
| 3 | Matt | 25 | 01/01/2021 |

And I'd like to run a query that returns the following values based on a relevant effective date. For example:

Effective date: 01/02/2023

| ID | Name | Value | Effective From |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 100 | 01/01/2023 |
| 2 | Sam | 100 | 01/01/2023 |
| 3 | Matt | 100 | 01/01/2023 |

If I choose an Effective date of: 01/01/2021

| ID | Name | Value | Effective From |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 25 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2 | Sam | 25 | 01/01/2021 |
| 3 | Matt | 25 | 01/01/2021 |

The closest I've got is this, but it only returns the relevant row for the right person:

```
DECLARE    @ReportingDate date
SET    @ReportingDate = '01-01-2023'

SELECT     TOP 1
       ID, Name, Value, Effective From
FROM       Table
WHERE      Effective date<=@ReportingDate
ORDER BY   Effective date DESC,
```

Comment: Based on the syntax this is clearly SQL Server, not MySQL, so I have removed the tag. Please don't tag conflicting and irrelevant products, as it makes your question unclear.

Comment: Apologies. As mentioned in my post I'm new to this!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by creating a CTE with a calculation to show how many days apart the EffectiveFrom and your provided date is, and then use this to add a row number. I would then select from the CTE and only get 1 row per person.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Example;
CREATE TABLE #Example (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(4), [Value] INT, EffectiveFrom DATE);
INSERT INTO #Example (ID, Name, Value, EffectiveFrom)
VALUES (1, 'Tom', 100, '2023-01-01'),
       (1, 'Tom', 50, '2022-01-01'),
       (1, 'Tom', 25, '2021-01-01'),
       (2, 'Sam', 100, '2023-01-01'),
       (2, 'Sam', 50, '2022-01-01'),
       (2, 'Sam', 25, '2021-01-01'),
       (3, 'Matt', 100, '2023-01-01'),
       (3, 'Matt', 50, '2022-01-01'),
       (3, 'Matt', 25, '2021-01-01');

DECLARE @ProvidedDate DATE = '2023-02-01';

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT E.ID,
           E.Name,
           E.Value,
           E.EffectiveFrom,
           CASE
               WHEN @ProvidedDate >= E.EffectiveFrom THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, E.EffectiveFrom, @ProvidedDate)
               ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, @ProvidedDate, E.EffectiveFrom)
           END AS DaysApart,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.ID
                              ORDER BY CASE
                                           WHEN @ProvidedDate >= E.EffectiveFrom THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, E.EffectiveFrom, @ProvidedDate)
                                           ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, @ProvidedDate, E.EffectiveFrom)
                                       END
                        ) AS rn
    FROM #Example AS E
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE CTE.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. With this solution do the values need manually entering each time?  Some of our tables are much bigger so would be nice if there was a way to get around this! Thanks.

Comment: what values do you think need manually entering? the bit at the beginning is me recreating your example table, you just need to change #Example to your real table name  and tweak the alias etc.

Comment: Ah thanks! I've done some testing and it works great! thank you. 

Is there any way to scale this approach so that if this table was then left joined to another table with other information with different effective dates it could being back the relevant entry?